# how to disable gnome touchscreen keyboard entirely

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 17.04, ubuntu-gnome, touchscreen

I'm using ubuntu 17.04 with gnome shell 3.24.2 and the on-screen keyboard popping up keeps bugging me as my laptop has a hardware keyboard anyway. Is there any way to get rid of it completely?

*Edit in regard to the mark as duplicate:*

The keyboard popping up on my computer looks very similar to what pops up on Tom's [screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965250/on-screen-keyboard-popping-up-whenever-i-touch-screen). But the behavior is a little different. For me it does not appear when changing windows/apps or scroll within a browser. It does not even appear when marking text in a text field within a browser, be it a browser with touch support or without.

Some ways to make it appear on my computer are:

- Opening LibrOffice Writer
- Mark text in LibreOffice Writer on the touchscreen (in other text editors this is no problem)
- Jumping to the end of a line in LibreOffice Writer on the touchscreen (in other text editors this is no problem)
- Opening any text editor like Pluma, GEdit or Leafpad
- touching the status bar of any application

[image: screenshot]

On the screenshot above, I marked some text in LibreOffice Writer with the finger on the screen to make it appear.

I am still on Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome-Shell 3.24-2 installed parallel to Unity. After reading the discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67199/discussion-between-sudodus-and-tom-mercer) I checked if 'onboard' is installed, which it is, but that looks a little different to the keyboard popping up. Caribou does not seem to be installed and the keyboard feature wihin 'universal access' is disabled.

Comment: Well, did you try the suggested solutions in the answer(s) to the linked question? Somewhat different symptoms may still be caused by the same underlying issue or fixed by the same steps.

Comment: Well, after reading your comment I installed Keringar's extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1326/block-caribou/) and every issue seems to be solved. Even dragging and dropping chess figures as described in a comment on Keringar's answer works. Thanks for your suggestion.